# Oracle Linux 8.x - Performance Test (Stress / Load / IO / Network Usage / Memory Usage)

Tags: memory, io, oracle-linux, load, oracle

I want to do performance test on Oracle Linux 8 KVM guest server (It will be used as Application server (WLS 14c) and/or Oracle DB server).

What are the best tools I can provide this with? I saw an RPM called stress. Does it help in completing necessary tests for network, CPU, memory and I/O? Or how can I do them all individually in the most consistent way?

What are the most successful RPMs or system commands? (dd for example I/O)

Note: the servers are not used instantly, I want to create a virtual (contrived) load.

Thanks in advance and best regards.

Comment: the best tools to test the performance of a piece of hardware in your application is to have a representatitive application payload and run that as benchmark. Everything else is just meaningless numbers that benchmark sites publish as a means of making a living.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Hello Marcus. Yes, I agree. It is impossible to create a prod-like environment anyway. However, we see the benefits of such tests from time to time. For example; We noticed that there was corruption on a disk before we went live on our test systems. Once again, it helped us solve a problem for the CPU beforehand. My question is general, however if you know of a consistent tool that might help please suggest it.